# Package Installation Problem (Verification Failed)

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I have following strange problem. When I try to install any of the L3 packages (like `l3packages`, `l3build`, etc.) within the package manager I get:

> The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:
>   C:\Miktex Package Repository\l3packages.tar.lzma

I think the files are not corrupted because I tried installing it on another computer and it worked. I also tried using different repositories. Latex output is just:

> Fehler: running 'texi2dvi' on 'FILE.tex' failed LaTeX errors: ! LaTeX Error: File `xparse.sty' not found.

Does anybody know what's going on here? All other packages can be installed as far as I can tell. However, for other packages I also get a weird message, even though they are successfully installed.

The operation failed for some reason.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe
```

I have no idea why this happening, I would be grateful for some insight.

Comment: Have you tried updating MikTeX and then rerunning the installation process?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't update that easily as I am behind a company firewall which blocks on the fly installation from the Internet -> have to install each package manually. I am going to reinstall miktex tomorrow and see if this helps, extremely annoying...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and looked into the log. It said that this command had failed:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64>initexmf.exe --mklinks --mkmaps
```

I opened a command prompt in administrator mode and executed it and now pdflatex is working for me. I first tried to execute that in a non-administrator window and it failed because of permissions. So I am pretty sure this is the right solution.